# Can you intermix legacy and normal BQ in a single statement?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a sql script that I need to execute via the console.  However, the middle portion of the script is a bit unwieldy to write in the normal `sql` but using legacy sql its quite succinct.

I can break it out into 3 commands

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "<sql1>"
bq query --use_legacy_sql=true "<sql2>"
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "<sql3>"
```

But would prefer to keep it as a single script.  Is possible to set this flag live within the sql code?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK you cannot combine legacy and normal SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jeremy, we cannot mix legacy and standard SQL queries in a script.

More information on legacy and standard SQL is mentioned in this [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).